# Stackwise and RSTP states of other uplinks

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree

Assuming I've got four C3750X, each side stacked with Stackwise Plus and using RSTP:

```
C1 -----10Gbit----- C2
|                    |
|                    |
SW                  SW
|                    |
|                    |
C3 -----10Gbit----- C4
```

Would the second 10Gbit-uplink in RSTP alternate or backup state?

---

Edit: The two 10Gbit lines are provided by two different carriers with two different round-time-trips (due to different fibre lengths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you configure STP.

PVSTP and PVSTP+ supports per-VLAN STP, wich means that you can chose one uplink for a certain set of VLAN's and another uplink for other VLAN's.

Either way - there is no need to run separate uplinks when you have a switch stack on each end. Just configure a etherchannel between the switches, using one port on each physical switch. This will give you the redundancy (and load balancing) you are after.

For more information:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12.2_53_se/configuration/guide/swethchl.html#wp1342634

Comment: Definitely would use etherchannel.

Comment: Etherchannel might add some problems due to the different round-time trips.

Comment: So make them routed connections with a higher metric on the faster line.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with routed connections? Layer 3 routing would be not an option.

Answer (score 2):

One of the 10Gig links would be in alternate blocking state and one would be forwarding if I read that diagram correctly.

Comment: Yes, but is the blocking state backup or alternate? It matters because of the RSTP convergence times.

Comment: CyberOptic: can't you just log in to the switch and check? I can't see much need for a 3rd link in this setup.

Comment: The switches are yet to be bought. C1 & C3 are onsite, C2 & C4 are remote. There are two carriers providing fibre, one shall be backup.

Comment: Sorry, should have read more closely - it would be in ALTN-BLK state. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In that topology, the blocked port will be in Alternate state.